# Twilio Functions connecting to Postgres Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I'm having some trouble querying a database in postgres. I have no issues querying the db when not using Twilio functions but when trying to query via Twilio functions I'm getting blank results. I suspect that it's not connecting properly (returns a 200 response but the body is blank).

I'm not sure if there's something specific to Twilio I need to do. I will add that I'm pretty new to JavaScript so it's very possible I'm missing something obvious here.

```
const{Client} = require('pg')


exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback){
        
        const client = new Client({
            user: context.DO_USER,
            password : context.DO_PW,
            host : context.DO_HOST,
            port : context.DO_PORT,
            database : context.DO_DB_DEV,
            ssl: context.DO_SSL
            })

    try{
        await client.connect();
        console.log("connected successfully");
        const results = await client.query("select * from customers where customer_id = $1", [event.customer_id]);
        await client.end();
        callback(null, results.rows[0]);
    
} catch(e)
    {
    console.log(`error: ${e}`);
    callback(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue is your successful callback has the parameter in the wrong location, should be: `return callback(null, results.rows[0]);`

Comment: @Alan thanks for catching that.Unfortunately, it still is timing out

Comment: Using MySQL but does this help any? Connect to Your Local Database Using Twilio Functions - https://www.twilio.com/blog/connect-local-database-twilio-functions

Comment: To me, it sounds like some async issue, the code looks correct (but I don't know the Postgres bits).

Comment: @Alan I figured it out, was pretty dumb but it was an issue with the firewall and refusing connection from Twilio. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What was the firewall issue? I am having the same problem