# Twilio function timing out on connecting to AWS postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, twilio, amazon-rds

I'm trying to run the below code as a twilio function. I am able to connect locally to the AWS RDS postgres database using the same credentials as in the connection string; however, my twilio function is timing out on the line
`await client.connect();`.

I'm not sure what this means or how to debug it. Is it rejecting the credentials or could there be a firewall issue between twilio and my rds database? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
const{Client} = require('pg');

exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log("HELLO")
  const connectionString = 'postgresql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE'
  const client = new Client({connectionString,})

  // Try actually connecting to the database
  try {
    console.log("in the try");
    await client.connect();
    console.log("connected successfully");
    return callback();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error wah");
    console.log(e);
    return callback(e);
  }
  return callback();
};
```

Comment: Curious if this helps from a former poster? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872286/twilio-functions-connecting-to-postgres-error

Comment: Thanks! I saw their last comment is "I figured it out, was pretty dumb but it was an issue with the firewall and refusing connection from Twilio. Thanks for the help!", indicating a firewall. I'm not sure what the firewall would be though or how to fix it. I can access the database locally (and it is 'publicly available' on aws), and I'm just on my personal computer, so there isn't a company firewall. Not sure if twilio or aws have other firewalls to get through.

Comment: Is it running on an EC2 instance? Twilio doesn't have any outbound firewall but Amazon may for EC2 instances or other offerings like Lightsail.

Comment: Good catch - I had a firewall up on AWS - once I whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 IP, now it works; however, I don't want the database open to the whole world..so now I am figuring out what to do