# How to securely write sms output of twilio studio flow to aws rds database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, security, twilio

I have a twilio studio flow for sms and I want to write the sms output to an aws rds postgres database. I initially accomplished this by creating a twilio function that is triggered at the end of the flow and writes to the db ([Twilio function timing out on connecting to AWS postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944397/twilio-function-timing-out-on-connecting-to-aws-postgres-database)).

However, since Twilio doesn't have static IPs, I could only get this to work by opening my database to anybody (whitelisting the 0.0.0.0/0 IP). This seems not great for security, so I'm trying to figure out a more secure way. I've read Twilio's security docs and it seems like I might be able to approach this differently by setting up a web server where Twilio sends the results to, but this seems much more complicated if my end goal is just to store the sms in the database (& I don't really understand how to do this). Is setting up an http request the way to go? Alternatively, could something like zapier help?

Any thoughts on secure (& ideally not too complicated) ways to accomplish this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use Twilio Event streams as a trigger (to reach out to Twilio) and use the Studio Executions endpoint to view what transpired on the Studio Execution.

You could also use the [Twilio X-Twilio-Signature validation or basic authentication](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security) over HTTPS to secure your endpoint.

[Streaming Studio Flow Executions with Event Streams](https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-studio-event-streams)

[Fetch Execution Context](https://Fetch%20Execution%20Context)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm looking into this.

Comment: I got the tutorial working for event streams: https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/eventstreams-quickstart, but I don't see a way to get the message text (the "context" variable in "com.twilio.studio.flow.execution.ended") via this method. Do you know if that is possible? It looks like your 3rd link might answer this question, but the link doesn't work for me. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you are saying - I should just use the event stream as a trigger to them separate reach out to twilio to GET the execution flow details via the studio executions endpoint